# How to find Dropbox layer through CartoDB navigator?

Tags: carto

this may well be just UI feedback for the CartoDB people (in which case I apologise for posting here).

I would like to make sure I'm not missing something obvious in the way CartoDB expects a user to locate a new layer for upload via Dropbox.

On an existing visualisation the user is given a [+] symbol which launches a "New Layer" selector widget. The widget presents a range of possible sources, including Dropbox.

Choosing Dropbox prompts an authentication process. When complete, CartoDB immediately scans the entire Dropbox: there is no opportunity to subselect a folder of interest.

After the scan is complete, CartoDB presents the user with a list of file titles with the path printed below each filename.

There is no clear way to sort, filter, or navigate this list...or is there?  This is my question. Please see attached screenshot.

In our case there are thousands of files in hundreds of folders, only a small percentage are spatial files.

What is the CartoDB concept on navigating Dropbox properly?

[image: screenshot of CartoDB-Dropbox navigator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organizing the list with folders is in our roadmap, but is not available yet as you may notice. :-)

Comment: For what it's worth: in FireFox, the modal window is searchable. That's a bit of help in locating a target amongst the jumble.